# showing $\mu$ is a measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathbf{A})$ be a measure space and $\mu$ a non-negative finitely additive set function with $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$. Suppose whenever $A_j$ is a sequence of elements of $\mathbf{A}$ that decreases to $\emptyset$, then $\lim_{j \to \infty} \mu(A_j)=0$, then show $\mu$ is a measure.

$\textbf{My attempt}.$

All that is left is to prove countable additivity. And for disjoint measurable sets consider

$$B_k:=A_k \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{k-1}A_j = A_k \cap (\cup_{j=1}^{k-1}A_j)^c$$

which are measurable since its intersections, unions, and complements. All that is left to show is that

$$\mu(\cup_{j=1}^\infty B_j)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(B_j).$$

but i have finite additivity and the measure of the intersection of the $A_j$'s is zero by MCT for measurable sets. Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated. Also sorry if this is a dup, i wasnt sure it had been asked.